# Popup max height java

Tags: java, android

I have a popup menu in Java code that activates when I press a button. It is coded to get a language and translate text (in a different function) to a different language. Since I have so many languages, the popup menu reaches the top of the page, and there isn't any space from the top of the user's phone and the start of the popup menu. Is there a way to edit the height of the menu so that it can only be a max of 50dp (example) without changing the function?
If so, please add example!

Here is the code for the popup:

```
private void showTranslateDialog() {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), translateBtn);
    popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    

    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Afrikaans");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Arabic");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 3, 3, "Belarusian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 4, 4, "Bulgarian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 5, 5, "Bengali");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 6, 6, "Catalan");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 7, 7, "Czech");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 8, 8, "Welsh");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 9, 9, "Danish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 10, 10, "German");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 11, 11, "Greek");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 12, 12, "English");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 13, 13, "Esperanto");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 14, 14, "Spanish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 15, 15, "Estonian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 16, 16, "Persian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 17, 17, "Finnish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 18, 18, "French");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 19, 19, "Irish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 20, 20, "Galician");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 21, 21, "Gujarati");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 22, 22, "Hebrew");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 23, 23, "Hindi");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 24, 24, "Croatian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 25, 25, "Haitian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 26, 26, "Hungarian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 27, 27, "Indonesian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 28, 28, "Icelandic");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 29, 29, "Italian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 30, 30, "Japanese");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 31, 31, "Georgian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 32, 32, "Kannada");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 33, 33, "Korean");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 34, 34, "Lithuanian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 35, 35, "Latvian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 36, 36, "Macedonian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 37, 37, "Marathi");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 38, 38, "Malay");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 39, 39, "Maltese");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 40, 40, "Dutch");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 41, 41, "Norwegian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 42, 42, "Polish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 43, 43, "Portuguese");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 44, 44, "Romanian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 45, 45, "Russian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 46, 46, "Slovak");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 47, 47, "Slovenian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 48, 48, "Albanian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 49, 49, "Swedish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 50, 50, "Swahili");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 51, 51, "Tamil");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 52, 52, "Telugu");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 53, 53, "Thai");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 54, 54, "Tagalog");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 55, 55, "Turkish");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 56, 56, "Ukrainian");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 57, 57, "Urdu");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 58, 58, "Vietnamese");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 59, 59, "Chinese");

    popupMenu.show();

    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(menuItem -> {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case 1: translateTo = "af"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Afrikaans
            case 2: translateTo = "ar"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Arabic
            case 3: translateTo = "be"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Belarusian
            case 4: translateTo = "bg"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Bulgarian
            case 5: translateTo = "bn"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Bengali
            case 6: translateTo = "ca"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Catalan
            case 7: translateTo = "cs"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Czech
            case 8: translateTo = "cy"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Welsh
            case 9: translateTo = "da"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Danish
            case 10: translateTo = "de"; identifyLanguage(); break; // German
            case 11: translateTo = "el"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Greek
            case 12: translateTo = "en"; identifyLanguage(); break; // English
            case 13: translateTo = "eo"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Esperanto
            case 14: translateTo = "es"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Spanish
            case 15: translateTo = "et"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Estonian
            case 16: translateTo = "fa"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Persian
            case 17: translateTo = "fi"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Finnish
            case 18: translateTo = "fr"; identifyLanguage(); break; // French
            case 19: translateTo = "ga"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Irish
            case 20: translateTo = "gl"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Galician
            case 21: translateTo = "gu"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Gujarati
            case 22: translateTo = "he"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Hebrew
            case 23: translateTo = "hi"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Hindi
            case 24: translateTo = "hr"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Croatian
            case 25: translateTo = "ht"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Haitian
            case 26: translateTo = "hu"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Hungarian
            case 27: translateTo = "id"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Indonesian
            case 28: translateTo = "is"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Icelandic
            case 29: translateTo = "it"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Italian
            case 30: translateTo = "ja"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Japanese
            case 31: translateTo = "ka"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Georgian
            case 32: translateTo = "kn"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Kannada
            case 33: translateTo = "ko"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Korean
            case 34: translateTo = "lt"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Lithuanian
            case 35: translateTo = "lv"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Latvian
            case 36: translateTo = "mk"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Macedonian
            case 37: translateTo = "mr"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Marathi
            case 38: translateTo = "ms"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Malay
            case 39: translateTo = "mt"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Maltese
            case 40: translateTo = "nl"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Dutch
            case 41: translateTo = "no"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Norwegian
            case 42: translateTo = "pl"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Polish
            case 43: translateTo = "pt"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Portuguese
            case 44: translateTo = "ro"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Romanian
            case 45: translateTo = "ru"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Russian
            case 46: translateTo = "sk"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Slovakian
            case 47: translateTo = "sl"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Slovenian
            case 48: translateTo = "sq"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Albanian
            case 49: translateTo = "sv"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Swedish
            case 50: translateTo = "sw"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Swahili
            case 51: translateTo = "ta"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Tamil
            case 52: translateTo = "te"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Telugu
            case 53: translateTo = "th"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Thai
            case 54: translateTo = "tl"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Tagalog
            case 55: translateTo = "tr"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Turkish
            case 56: translateTo = "uk"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Ukrainian
            case 57: translateTo = "ur"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Urdu
            case 58: translateTo = "vi"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Vietnamese
            case 60: translateTo = "zh"; identifyLanguage(); break; // Chinese
        }
        return true;
    });
}
private boolean hasInstallPermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom style for you PopupMenu in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="CustomPopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:maxHeight">50dp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply the style when instantiating the PopupMenu

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.CustomPopupMenu), translateBtn);
```